# Using ActiveX control in .NET CF

Tags: compact-framework, activex

I want to use ActiveX in my .NET CF project
as Microsoft explained at this link:

[Hosting ActiveX Controls in the .NET Compact Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx)

I need to download Host_ActiveX_Controls.msi but link is dead
any other solution or valid link to Host_ActiveX_Controls.msi is needed

Answer (score 2):

The code in the original article had a leak in it anyway, so the fact that it's down maybe isn't such a bad thing.  There's an updated, non-leaky version [hosted on my blog here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2008/08/14/bug-in-msdn-activex-hosting-code/).

Comment: Ist there real-world "enterpise-level" ActiveX components for WinCE devices except Windows Media Player and Flash Player?

Comment: Sure.  Most of them are purpose-built by the companies making the devices and used in a specific application for a specific vertical.  I've never really seen much as far as "third-party, off the shelf COM widgets" but I've seen plenty of customer-specific COM stuff.

Comment: thanx but on ur blog there is only axhost class not other required class